# Aspect ratio of a triangle of a meshed surface

Tags: c++, math, mesh

I need to calculate the aspect ratio of a triangle. I have the 3 points, and therefore I have the lengths and midpoints. I was attempting to use [this](https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Ansys/17.0/en-us/help/wb_fem/femod_aspect_triangle.html) tutorial (although its not much of one in my opinion), but it is very vague and doesn't give much information. Could someone elaborate, specifically on the rectangle creation part, or even share a bit of c++ code to solve this problem?

To James's solution:

```
double s = (a + b + c) / 2.0;
double AR = (a * b * c) / (8.0 * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
```

@James:

Cubit reports the following:

```
Function Name  Average      Std Dev      Minimum     Maximum
-------------  ---------    ---------    ---------   ---------
Aspect Ratio   1.000e+00    7.371e-04    1.000e+00   1.010e+00
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Your formula reports the following:

```
Function Name  Average    Minimum    Maximum
-------------  ---------  --------   -------
Aspect Ratio   1.00006    1.000000   1.00972
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Define "aspect ratio of triangle". Is that its narrowest possible dimension/diameter to the longest one?

Comment: Aha, length of the longest side, to the height (if we lay the triangle on that side, so to speak).

Comment: What I would do is project one of the shorter sides (as a vector) onto the longer side. The delta between that projected vector and the original one is a vector whose length is the height of the triangle.

Comment: @Kaz This is in relation to a meshed surface, just to clarify.

Comment: The usefulness of the finding the largest aspect ratio is to determine the quality of the mesh for use in computational electromagnetic solvers. The closer the ratio is to 1, the better and more accurate a mesh is to the geometric volume it represents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are the definitions of aspect ratio for triangles I know:

Aspect ratio of a triangle is the ratio of the longest edge to shortest edge (so equilateral triangle has aspect ratio 1).

Aspect ratio of a triangle is the ratio of the circumradius to twice its inradius, so `AR = abc/(8(s-a)(s-b)(s-c))` where `a,b,c` are the lengths of sides of the triangle and `s = (a+b+c)/2`. So, if `a=b=c`, then the aspect ratio is 1.

These are much easier to calculate than what you've given.

Comment: Thank you, and if I recall correctly, it was briefly mentioned to me that that example I provided was incorrect, but it was said in passing, and was the only thing that was returned by Google that was useful / made some sense.

Comment: I'm getting minimum ratios of ~ .02 and maximums of 49. My average is 1.1, so the average is about right (most of the triangles are equilateral). But shouldn't at least the minimum be near 1, and the maximum not so high? If I just take the ratio of the shortest sides and longest sides, I get ~1.0001 and ~4.5 respectively.

Comment: @Drise Are you sure you implemented the formula correctly? The aspect ratio should be >= 1. The maximums can be fairly high depending on the triangles.

Comment: Check my implementation above.

Comment: I've added the exact reportings from Cubit, a modeling and meshing program, and what your formula produces.

Comment: @Drise You have a typo in your formula. You have `(s-b)(s-b)` when it should be `(s-b)(s-c)`.

Comment: I'm quite embarrassed. Thank you for noticing... :/

Comment: I've fixed the comparison statistics I posted for verification. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Just FYI, typically aspect ratios of > 1.5 are considered "bad."

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of the circumradius to twice the inradius is the correct definition.  There is a slightly simpler formula:
AR = a*b*c/((b+c-a)*(c+a-b)*(a+b-c))